# Postal Code model field shows up as State list in Admin

Tags: django, postal-code, django-contrib

Not sure, but I think this may be a bug?

Here is my model:

```
class Property(models.Model):
Name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
Description = models.TextField(default="Description Not Available")
Address = models.CharField(max_length=60, default="Not Available")
Address2 = models.CharField(max_length=60,null=True)
City = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=True)
State = usa_model.USStateField(null=True)
Code = usa_model.USPostalCodeField(null=True)
Phone = usa_model.PhoneNumberField(null=True)
```

[image]

Am I missing something?

-Kerry

Comment: and does `State` shows postal codes?

Comment: Nope it shows states as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for the [US Zip Code Form Field?](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/localflavor/#django.contrib.localflavor.us.forms.USZipCodeField)

The `USPostalCodeField` uses a list of the states + a few extras:

```
COFA_STATES = (
    ('FM', 'Federated States of Micronesia'),
    ('MH', 'Marshall Islands'),
    ('PW', 'Palau'),
)
```

At `django.contrib.localflavor.us.us_states`

```
# USStateField
STATE_CHOICES = tuple(sorted(US_STATES + US_TERRITORIES + ARMED_FORCES_STATES, key=lambda obj: obj[1]))

# USPostalCodeField
USPS_CHOICES = tuple(sorted(US_STATES + US_TERRITORIES + ARMED_FORCES_STATES + COFA_STATES, key=lambda obj: obj[1]))
```

Comment: Ah I see. So what should my model be? integer max_length=5? or CharField max=10? Also how would I add the Form Field to the admin side?    Thanks!

Comment: `CharField`, since validation accepts XXXX-XXXX. For the admin, just specify a ModelForm with one field: `Code = ...USZipCodeField` and override `ModelAdmin.form` with your ModelForm - should be like 6 lines of code :)

Comment: Then if you are using ModelForm, it will just use the text field without any validation. So how do you make it validate correctly when using ModelAdmin?

Comment: @miki725: read my comment above, define your form then pass it to the ModelAdmin form attribute.

Comment: sorry, did not see that. thanx